# how to set the ans length using huggingface

Tags: large-language-model, huggingface, openaiembeddings

I am using hugging face for questions and answers from the pdf. How to set the limit of answers length?

```py
tytokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("HuggingFaceH4/zephyr-7b-beta", eos_token_id =['Question:'])
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("HuggingFaceH4/zephyr-7b-beta", low_cpu_mem_usage=True, torch_dtype=torch.float16, load_in_8bit=True )
pipe = pipeline(task="text-generation", model=model,tokenizer=tokenizer, max_new_tokens=50)
```

Comment: Your title has nothing to do with the question. You'll get better answers if you change the title.